# How to split string by multiple pairs of delimiters

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Is there a way to split string by delimiters if delimiters are pairs enclosing required text?

E.g. If source string is:

```
[Text1] [Text2] [Text3] ...
```

I want to have result as

```
Text1
Text2
Text3
```

Function Text.BetweenDelimiters picks up only first pair of [].
I guess I need somehow to create a loop. In e.g. Python it is a few lines of code. I cannot figure out how to do it in M.
If something like that s possible do in DAX, that would go too.

Comment: Add some sample data with your expected output.

Comment: Note that the M-language is specialized on ETL unlike DAX or Python.

Comment: did anyone's answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

1. replace "] [" with ";"
2. remove "[" and "]"
3. split by ";"
4. unpivot columns

```
let
    Source = Table.FromList(
        {
            "[Text1] [Text2] [Text3]", 
            "[Text4] [Text5] [Text6]"
        }, 
        null, {"Text"}
    ),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(
        Source,"] [",";",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Text"}),
    #"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(
        #"Replaced Value","[","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Text"}),
    #"Replaced Value2" = Table.ReplaceValue(
        #"Replaced Value1","]","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Text"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(
        #"Replaced Value2", "Text", 
        Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), 
        {"Text.1", "Text.2", "Text.3"}
    ),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
        #"Split Column by Delimiter",
        {
            {"Text.1", type text}, 
            {"Text.2", type text}, 
            {"Text.3", type text}
        }
    ),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(
        #"Changed Type", {}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(
        #"Unpivoted Columns",{"Attribute"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

The way you put your "sample data" you can even omit step 1 and split by " ".

Answer (score 0):

One way .. split on **]  [** then replace the two odd-men odd:

right click .. split column .. by delimeter.  Use ] [ and split into rows

[image]

right click and replace **[** with nothing

right click and replace **]** with nothing

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("] [", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Column1"),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Split Column by Delimiter","[","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Column1"}),
#"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value","]","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Column1"})
 in  #"Replaced Value1"
```

[image]